# How to access the methods for my custom UITableViewCell in my viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a question about accessing methods that I’ve added to a custom class. I created a custom UITableViewCell class and added two methods to it. I’m trying to access those methods in my view controller but somehow don’t see them as options. I’ve registered the cell in a function that runs in `viewDidLoad()` and I create an instance (I think) within `cellForRowAt indexPath` when run `cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: cellId) as! CustomCell1`. Right after I dequeue the cell I try doing `cell.configure(...` but don’t see my “configure” method as an option. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the code for my custom cell:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell1: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure() {
        print("Cell got configured")
    }
}
```

And this is my View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let cellId = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(table)
        table.register(CustomCell1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        table.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        table.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return "Value 1 Cell Style | Section: \(section) - "
        default:
            return "Default cell header title"
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: cellId) as! CustomCell1
            cell.configure(...) // This method isn't working
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Title Label \(indexPath.row) - "
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail label"
        default:
            cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Title Label \(indexPath.row) - "
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail Label"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - your implementation of `cellForRowAt` is all wrong. Do not create the cells yourself. That's the job of `dequeueReusableCell`. Please review the countless table view tutorials that show the correct way to setup custom cells in a table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using of dequeueReusableCell is not the right way,

To make your code better: use different cell identifier for the custom and the default cell

```
let cell1Id = "cell1"        
let defaultCellId = "defaultCell"
```

then register the cells

```
table.register(CustomCell1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cell1Id)
table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: defaultCellId)
```

Now you can let dequeueReusableCell function to create and reuse the cells:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cell1Id, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell1
        cell.configure()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Title Label \(indexPath.row) - "
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail label"
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: defaultCellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Title Label \(indexPath.row) - "
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail Label"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Happy coding!